# Using decimals in QGIS raster calculator

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I am using the QGIS raster calculator to change the values of pixels of a specified value to a different value.  For instance, to change all pixels with a value of -32768 to a value of -999, I can use the following formula:

```
("RasterFileName@1"=-32768)*(-999)+("RasterFileName@1"!=-32768)*("RasterFileName@1")
```

This seems to work for all integer values, including positive, negative and zero.  However, it only works for some decimal values.  For example, the raster calculator can correctly identify and change a pixel with a value of -0.5, but not a pixel with a value of 0.1 or -0.6.

The raster calculator can change the value of a pixel to any of these decimal values, it just can't recognize these decimal values in an existing raster.

Any ideas on what is happening or is there a better way to change the values of pixels in QGIS?

The raster calculator seems to be a quirky tool.  It also doesn't recognize -3.40282347e+38 (sometimes used as a nodata value).